# Android - Keeping clicked on items highlighted in ListView (and in memory)

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have an app whereby i am accessing a RESt webservice and presenting the request in listview (ListFrragment). It is essentially a list of articles. What i am trying to achieve is when a user clicks on an item in listview (expands article in ViewPager) is stays highlighted (indicating that the article has been read).  The next time the user reloads this listview, all the item that have been read  is still highlighted.

I have have created a boolean variable "read" for each article. When a user clicks on this item, the "read" variable is assigned to TRUE. Then in the custom Adapter(extends arrayAdpater), i assign the background colour (in this case green) in getView for articles whose "read" value is TRUE. This does work, but what i am finding is that other items in the listview is also randomly turning green when i start to scroll up and down the listview without actually clicking on it.  I'm really stuck as i do not understand what is happening. Please can someone advise?

```
 public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int postion, long id) {
    Article a = ((toReadListAdapter) getListAdapter()).getItem(postion);

    // set read attribute to TRUE
    a.setRead(true);
    saveToReadList(toReadList);

   // Open via ViewPager
   Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ReadingList_PagerActivity.class);
   startActivity(i);
```

Customer Adapter:

```
 // Defining custom adapter
private class toReadListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Article> {
    public toReadListAdapter(ArrayList<Article> listToRead) {
        super(getActivity(), 0, listToRead);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.new_articlelistfragment, null);
        }

        Article en = getItem(position);

        Log.d(TAG, "Showing articles: " + position + "/ pmid: " + en.getId());
        Log.e(TAG, "isRead value: " + en.isRead());

        if(en.isRead() == true){
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#C8E6C9"));
        }

        ......
        return convertView;
```

Comment: Due to the recycling that takes place in a ListView you need to always provide defaults to the changes you make. So in your getView() method you change the background to that color but you need to also add a else clause to set the background to the default color of your row.

Comment: Your advice worked.  Thank you for taking the tie to help me. I would vote your reply up but i do not have enough rep points to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the getView

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.new_articlelistfragment, null);
    }

    Article en = getItem(position);

    if(en.isRead() == true){
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#C8E6C9"));
    }
    else{
    // put the default color
    convertView.setBackgroundColor( );
    }

    ......
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not applying the default color. Add an else statement in get view method